# Why does jQuery Mobile in Chrome (iOS) remove URL parameters when closing popup?

Tags: jquery, ios, google-chrome, jquery-mobile

I am running jQuery Mobile 1.4.5 with jQuery 1.12.0 and would like to open a popup. This works, but closing the popup results in loosing the URI parameters of the original page which in this case leads to loosing pagination info. This only happens in iOS Chrome version 49.0.2623.73. It does not happen in Safari or FF.

```
<div data-role="popup"  data-arrow="b" id="mypop" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all" data-dismissible="true" data-add-back-btn="true" data-transition="pop" data-overlay-theme="a">
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a>
    <div class="popup">
        <form action="/test.php" method="post" name="subscribe_cat_form" onsubmit="return check_subscribe_cat_form(this);" >              
            <!--form-->   
        </form>
    </div>
    <p>info</p>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).on('pageinit', '.ui-page',function(event){
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#mypop").popup( "open", { x: 10, y: 10 });
        }, 1000);
    })
</script>
```

The URL parameters it is loosing are: index.php?page=2
It simply strips the parameters upon close and opens index.php

The closing event can be the button or simply tapping next to the popup.

Chrome on Android seems not to be affected.

Comment: It seems to work correctly with Chrome version 49.0.2623.87 on MS Windows 10: https://www.elitesystemer.no/demo/test/test.php?page=2. The popup adds '#&ui-state=dialog' to the URL, but that can be disabled with the data attribute data-history="false" (http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/#option-history)

Comment: Thank you! This has solved the problem.